# Visual Studio 2012 ExtJS IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, extjs, visual-studio-2013, extjs4.2

Is there a way to get ExtJS intelliSense in Visual Studio 2012?  This combined with the new JavaScript support would make my ExtJS projects much easier to code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding reference path to ext-all within your js file will provide support.  Specifically, using the ext-all-debug-w-comments provides supporting comments provided by sencha.

```
/// <reference path="../../../ext/ext-all-debug-w-comments.js" />
```