# ExtJS IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: extjs, visual-studio-2013, extjs5

How do I enable intellisense for Ext JS 5.0 in Visual Studio 2013?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155317/visual-studio-2012-extjs-intellisense) refers to a file named `ext-all-debug-w-comments.js`, which I don't see in the Ext JS 5.0 package I downloaded. Nor do I see the `ext-all-debug-full.js` mentioned [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?287329-Does-Visual-Studio-2013-support-the-intellisense-of-EXTJS-5).

Answer (score 1):

in ExtJS 5 its `build/ext-all-debug.js`

Comment: Adding references to that file in either _references.js or in the top the javascript file where I would like intellisense to kick, doesn't work.